# Not able to click on element with unselectable='on' in chrome using webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

There is a drop down with an arrow on the side which opens up a sub menu. I am not able to click on the dropdown in chrome whereas its working in ie.

I tried hover and click and actions build too. But it's not working.

The code is as follows:

```
<div id="navigatortab" class=" x-plain undefined sd_nav_tabpanel x-border-panel" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1600px;">
<div id="ext-gen32" class="support-servicedesk-navigator">
<table id="ext-comp-1014" class="x-btn support-servicedesk-sb support-servicedesk-sbactive caseMru x-btn-noicon" cellspacing="0" style="width: 180px; height: 26px; background-image: none; background-color: transparent;">
<tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="x-btn-ml">
<td class="x-btn-mc">
<em id="ext-gen41" class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on">
<button id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text" type="button">
<div class="mruIcon"></div>
<span>Cases</span>
</button>
</em>
</td>
<td class="x-btn-mr">
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code from Webdriver?

Comment: AFAIK, `unselectable="on"` attribute is used _only_ in IE and Opera. Maybe, that's the point? As @screenmutt said, post your code and expected/actual behaviour and exception message, if you get one.